# jquery how to change the class name and attach the event handlers for the changed class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the class of a div element and write click function for class names.

1. on clicking 'editthis' I am logging 'editthis' and removing the class 'editthis' and adding the class 'savethis'
2. I have click function for class 'savethis' but this click event is not executed it logs 'editthis' always, but the class name changed to 'savethis', but the click function on 'savethis' is not executed

   ```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
     $(function(){
       $('.editthis').on('click', function(){
         console.log('editthis');                              
         $(this).text('SAVE');
         $(this).removeClass('editthis');
         $(this).addClass('savethis');
     });
      $('.savethis').on('click', function(){
         console.log('savethis');                              
         $(this).text('EDIT');
         $(this).removeClass('savethis');
         $(this).addClass('editthis');
       });
    });
   </script>


    <div class="editthis">EDIT</div>
   ```

if it is not clear please ask I will try to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the event handling to a parent element.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.editthis', function(){
      console.log('editthis');                              
      $(this).text('SAVE');
      $(this).removeClass('editthis');
      $(this).addClass('savethis');
  }).on('click', '.savethis', function(){
      console.log('savethis');                              
      $(this).text('EDIT');
      $(this).removeClass('savethis');
      $(this).addClass('editthis');
  });
});
```

The `document` i put would work, but it is best to delegate to a parent closer to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.editthis', function(){
      console.log('editthis');                              
      $(this).text('SAVE');
      $(this).removeClass('editthis');
      $(this).addClass('savethis');
  });
  $(document).on('click','.savethis', function(){
     console.log('savethis');                              
     $(this).text('EDIT');
     $(this).removeClass('savethis');
     $(this).addClass('editthis');
   });
 });
</script>
```